# File Conversion using ogr2ogr gui

Tags: mapinfo, ogr2ogr, tab

I have used 'ogr2ogr' for ESRI shape files conversion to Mapinfo tab files, but issue is that as soon as I open those converted .tab files over Mapinfo, the software stop working with a message

> MapInfo Professional has stopped working, Close the program.

Please help me out with the solution for the same.

I need a software which could convert n-number of ESRI shape files at one go into MapInfo tab files.

Comment: What version of MapInfo you have ?

Comment: ogr2gui is a bit old. I would have a try with ogr2ogr command line from GDAL 2.0 which was released a few days ago. And a small sample of data and exact ogr2ogr command that you used might help also a lot.

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Professional have additional software called  "Universal Translator" or in recent versions "FME Quick Translator"  that can do this without a problem.

You can access it through "Tools" menu as

Tools/Universal Translator

[image]

Comment: I had gone through this tool as well but MapInfo's Universal Translator tool took more time to convert large files with complicated geometry and having more number of nodes.

Comment: So UT took more time, but did it at least generate tab files that could be opened by MapInfo Pro. You might have run into issues with the above because the tables didn't meet some of the limitations that the tab format has, such as character fields can be wider than 254.

Comment: Yes, MapInfo do convert the files via UT but as an alternative  I had tried ogr2ogr for file conversions. As suggested I had removed the unnecessary columns as well as reduced the column length but it doesn't work, the ogr2ogr output is same as before.